LM393 window comparator for switching
Please see attached, i want to driving out of LM393 to BC548 so that it acts as a switch for grounding pin7 (lm386) if LM393 generates output.
Is it possible to see it and tell me correct values for 2.2K and 10K resistors (blue box)?
Thank you. 

The LM386 Datasheet shows the BYPASS pin wired to 15k resistors:

I don't understand what exactly you're doing with it, but evidently no more than 2 * (5V) / (15k) ~= 0.67mA can flow through the pin at 5V supply.  BC548 has min hFE 110, which will be an effective switch for forced hFE of say 20 or less.  Thus we should have base current above 33µA.
As LM393 saturates to less than 0.2V at 50µA, we can pull down the base directly, and a 100k pull-up will suffice.  That is, R23 = 100k, series resistor 0, B-E resistor absent.
You don't mention the purpose of C16 so I cannot offer advice on whether these resistor values have any consequence to it.
The given values will also function, at the expense of somewhat higher current consumption. Given the use of bipolar ICs, I'm guessing supply consumption is not a concern.

Thank you. The LM393 schematic acts for generating a mute command for lm386. LM386 acts like mute if we connect pin7 to ground. So, if i understand correctly, do you think i only need to change value R23 from 10K to 100k?

There was an uV meter at output of LM393. I think the C16 is for it.

100k is only the maximum value.  R23 minimum could be about 4.7k in the same configuration, or down to about 1k with the base divider resistors in use. You don't need any change.

Thank you. So just remove  both 10K (Emitter-Base) and 2.2K (Base) ?

They're fine either way.

Thank you for your guidance. So, the original schematic is fine and it does not need any changing.
