Muting Audio with lm393 output
I have a problem in muting audio.
Please see attached, the top schematic is my audio schematic that produce an stable tone.
The bottom schematic is Mute command.
I want to mute my audio output completely if my bottom schematic (LM393, red line) has output.
Is it possible to guide me how to connect the red line (mute command) to which point of top schematic?



Are you able to add extra components? What is the intended voltage at the "Mute command" connection for each state, mute and not-mute? Could it be somewhere inbetween?

Yes, i can add extra components. Actually the red line was connected to an uA meter (500uA). I want to remove the meter and to show as mute action in audio. I think it needs a simple schematic between the two schematics. I hope you find a solution for this.

What is the intended voltage at the "Mute command" connection for each state, mute and not-mute?

Please again picture, the command mute was it (uA meter).

I do not know about voltage. Can you guide me how to measure it? I had a trying for muting via the following link, but its muting was not good (pin 7 lm386 via bc548 switching).       https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/725936/lm393-window-comparator-for-switching/725947?noredirect=1#comment1930814_725947

But sensitivity of BC548 was good and it shows a change in audio tone. Other words, sensitivity that the bc548 (with 2.2k and 10k resistor) showed was exactly equal to uA meter.

In fact, i am going to replace the uA meter as a mute in my Audio tone.

The comparators produce an output of ±5V, making this difficult to interface directly to the rest of the circuit. However, that same large swing does make it easier to employ a couple of extra transistors (MOSFETs), to make a poor-man's analogue switch:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I don't know whether a high or low signal should mute, so this might not do it the correct way around. No promises, but worth a shot.

Thank you for your helping dear S. Fitch. Actually my main purpose is that i have a big change ( silent) in my tone if the comparator generates any output (based on its sensitivity with R21). I will test it and notify here its result.  Can you tell me your means about high/low signal)? In my audio schematic, i always have a static tone at output (i think it is sine wave). I just want to disconnect temporally connection of audio part with LM386 if my comparator has any output.

@HFAR Your comparator output can be high (+5V) or low (-5V). Which one should cause the signal to be muted?

Please let me to check it with multimeter at output of comparator. Weather it is negative or positive voltage .

I connected one (red wire) probe of multimeter to output of comparator and other probe (black wire). my output voltage is negative.

According to my tests, i want to mute negative voltage (low,-5V)

@HFAR "other probe (multimeter black wire)" to where?

Black wire was connected to ground.

@HFAR then my suggested solution should work.

Thank you dear S. Fitch.

Dear Sir, please forgive me. Can you tell me how to change your schematic if i want to mute high (+5v)? I want to test both +/-5.

@HFAR You might be able to modify the comparator arrangement. I don't want to go any further than I already have, to be honest.

OK, Thank you dear sir.

Dear S. Fitch, I tested your schematic (BS170), it works but volume of my audio is very very low. Do you have any idea about the low volume?

@HFAR Is volume OK without the muting transistors M1 and M2? What are the voltages (wrt ground) at the gates of M1 and M2 in each state, mute, no-mute?
